# Как получить user_id в Facebook, имея ссылку на пост

Tags: facebook, beautiful-soup, facebook-graph-api

Через API, я так понял, такую вещь сделать нельзя. Но на данный момент, насколько я понял, какие-то сайты до сих пор узнают user_id.

Была идея сделать так:

```
soup = (request.text, 'lxml')
soup.find('div', '_5pcp _5lel _232_')
```

Но почему-то этот класс не находится, хотя если сделать просто поиск по `r`, все найдется отлично.

+ оказывается, метод не особо универсален - если в посте есть картинка, то структура страницы уже другая.

Буду очень рад предложениям.